# Incorrect duration of mp4 file under VLC

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, libav

I'm trying to stream from a user desired camera to a file (99% of the cases are mp4). So far so good, I've basically copied the [example](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/remuxing_8c-example.html) from ffmpeg. It does work, but the video has wrong `start time` under VLC. Under Windows Media Player it's fine. I have checked the segments duration of the `trak` box and seems that would be the problem. I can copy my code but it's the same as in the example. How can that be fixed? I've searched many different formulas and nothing seems to help.

[image]